# Light of Back button is not working on my Android mobile

Tags: buttons, troubleshooting

I have Android Fly F45 S. From yesterday I am suddenly seeing that my Android mobile back button light is not working. The back button is working but the light is not lighting. I have never dropped it anywhere. Please solve this

Comment: Whether the other button (right - options?) is lighting?

Comment: Yes others two are  lighting except the back button (right button) is not lighting.

Answer (score 0):

Do a factory reset of your device (Remember to take app and data backup before doing the reset).

If this doesn't solve the issue, it may be hardware issue (either LED gone bad or any physical damage happened).

Comment: Thanks so much KeshavaGN. Let's see  factory reset can solve that problem or not.